# Mismatch between the bar chart and the line graph on the same plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, pivot-table

I'm trying to concatenate two pivot tables plots into one

First pivot table plot:

```
df.pivot_table(["Number of students on the first module","Number of students on the second module"], age).plot(kind="bar", rot=0)
```

[First plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Meyty.png)

Second pivot table plot is:

```
df.pivot_table(["Students outflow"],age).plot()
```

[Second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCwze.png)

And then i'm trying to place them on one plot using following code:

```
ax = pivot_table(["Number of students on the first module","Number of students on the second module"], age).plot(kind="bar", rot=0)
df.pivot_table(["Students outflow"],age).plot(secondary_y=True,ax=ax)
ax.get_legend().set_bbox_to_anchor((1.1, 1.185))
plt.show()
```

And I got this plot:

[Concat plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Ecf.png)

Why is there a mismatch between two plots by x-axis?

Comment: Pandas uses a "categorical" axis for the bar plot and a "numeric" axis for the line plot.

Comment: A workaround to get both plot to use categorical axes is:  `df = df.sort_values('age'); df['age'] = df['age'].astype(str)`